# Slider and Angular routing issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm using slider in my web, it works when i used it in a simple page without Angular, but when i using Angular routing it does not work!! it makes me confuse, what is the problem?

this is the slider:

```
<div id="leo-slideshow" class="clearfix">
<div class="banner" style="padding-right: 20px !important;height:375px;padding: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow: visible;">
    <div class="columns-container">
        <div id="columns" class="container">

            <div id="slider_row" class="row">
                <div id="top_column" class="center_column col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <!-- Module HomeSlider -->
                    <div id="homepage-slider" class="col-xs-8  col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                        <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 779px; margin: 0px auto;">
                            <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 448px;">
                                <ul id="homeslider" style="max-height: 448px; width: 515%; position: relative; left: -2336.98px;">

                                    <li class="homeslider-container" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 779px;">
                                        <a href="http://www.prestashop.com/?utm_source=back-office&utm_medium=v16_homeslider&utm_campaign=back-office-EN&utm_content=download" title="sample-2">
                                            <img src="~/Content/Images/Slider/sample-2.jpg" width="779" height="448" alt="sample-2">
                                        </a>

                                    </li>
                                    <li class="homeslider-container" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 779px;">
                                        <a href="http://www.prestashop.com/?utm_source=back-office&utm_medium=v16_homeslider&utm_campaign=back-office-EN&utm_content=download" title="sample-3">
                                            <img src="~/Content/Images/Slider/sample-3.jpg" width="779" height="448" alt="sample-3">
                                        </a>

                                    </li>
                                    <li class="homeslider-container bx-clone" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 779px;">
                                        <a href="http://www.prestashop.com/?utm_source=back-office&utm_medium=v16_homeslider&utm_campaign=back-office-EN&utm_content=download" title="sample-1">
                                            <img src="~/Content/Images/Slider/sample-1.jpg" width="779" height="448" alt="sample-1">
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Module HomeSlider -->
                    <div id="htmlcontent_top " class="animation_group_165 animated fadeInUp ">
                        <ul class="htmlcontent-home clearfix row">
                            <li class="htmlcontent-item-1 col-xs-4  col-sm-4 col-md-4 pull-left ">
                                <a href="http://www.prestashop.com/" class="item-link" title="">
                                    <img src="~/Content/Images/SitePic/banner-img6.jpg" class="item-img " title="" alt="" width="381" height="219">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="htmlcontent-item-2 col-xs-4  col-sm-4 col-md-4 ">
                                <a href="http://www.prestashop.com/" class="item-link" title="">
                                    <img src="~/Content/Images/SitePic/banner-img7.jpg" class="item-img " title="" alt="" width="381" height="219">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (typeof(homeslider_speed) == 'undefined')
    homeslider_speed = 500;
if (typeof(homeslider_pause) == 'undefined')
    homeslider_pause = 3000;
if (typeof(homeslider_loop) == 'undefined')
    homeslider_loop = true;
if (typeof(homeslider_width) == 'undefined')
    homeslider_width = 779;


$('.homeslider-description').click(function () {
    window.location.href = $(this).prev('a').prop('href');
});

if ($('#htmlcontent_top').length > 0)
    $('#homepage-slider').addClass('col-xs-8');
else
    $('#homepage-slider').addClass('col-xs-12');

if (!!$.prototype.bxSlider)
    $('#homeslider').bxSlider({
        useCSS: false,
        maxSlides: 1,
        slideWidth: homeslider_width,
        infiniteLoop: homeslider_loop,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        pager: false,
        autoHover: true,
        auto: homeslider_loop,
        speed: parseInt(homeslider_speed),
        pause: homeslider_pause,
        controls: true
    });
  });
```

Note: i am using [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/).

Comment: Can you make [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) example?